# Can I aggregate work time for each user and for each tag using ClickUp?

Tags: clickup-api

I'm using ClickUp and want to aggregate each members working time with their tags both daily and weekly.

Ideal goal→

User A's working time in a day:

- Tag A 4 hours
- Tag B 2.5 hours
- Tag C 1.5 hous

User A's working time in a week:

- Tag A 16hours
- Tag B 20hours
- Tag C 4hours

What I did:

I downloaded the CSV file, but only I could do was aggregating working time by tags without each members workload. I also looked into Dashboard, but look like existing cards could not satisfy my request.

Any idea?